# quick fix keymap entry in IntelliJ IDE keymap

Tags: java, intellij-idea, keymapping

I was wondering if anyone knows's a keymap entry in IntelliJ that is equivalent to NetBeans alt + enter? I have looked all over and cant find anything... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, if you have been working on Netbeans and are compatible working with the shortcuts on it, you can modify the Keymaps to use Netbeans key maps as well -

Just follow *`Preferences -> Keymap -> Change the Keymaps and Apply`*

[image]

(Ya. I am using Mac OS X 10.5+)

You should be able to the shortcut that you were using in Netbeans.

---

Though if you believe in persisting with the current KeyMap irrespective of what you're using. You might want to use the [Important Keyboard Shortcuts Suggestion from JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/keyboard-shortcuts-you-cannot-miss.html) which again provides you the suggestion pivoted on the Keymap that you're using. Please do look at the one being used and use accordingly.

Comment: I do indeed realise this but even in NetBeans, I have heavily modified its keymap to my preference. So you don't know if there is? there is an overwhelming amount of Keymap options and I don't wanna take an hour or 2 looking through them